# What is the ICGC normalized_read_count?

Tags: rna-seq, public-databases

I downloaded gene expression data (`exp_seq`) from the [ICGC file browser](https://dcc.icgc.org/releases/current/Projects/BRCA-US).

For each sample and gene, the file contains a `normalized_read_count`.

What is that value? I couldn't find any information on the ICGC website. The values are definitly too low for TPM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By reading [this thread](http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=42911) on seqanswers and by comparing the data to TCGA, I figured out

- `raw_read_count` is the read count which you use as input for e.g. `DESeq2`. It has been estimated using [RSEM](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-12-323)
- `normalized_read_count` is equivalent to the `scaled_estimate` from TCGA. This is the *estimated fraction of transcripts made up by a given gene*, as estimated by RSEM. Multiplying this value with 1e6 yields the TPM.

Comment: Glad you could find it yourself! Many thanks for posting the answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is an essential information for a user of this data. I wonder why this information on the ICGC website itself though. I found a page describing the columns on github https://github.com/icgc-dcc/dcc-docs/blob/master/docs/dictionary/release-20/sequencing-based-gene-expression-expseq-primary-file-p.md. It does not explicitly say what `normalized_read_count` are. Also the page corresponds to one of the older release (20), not the current one (28).